# Polynomial algo for 2-SAT related algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, satisfiability, 2-satisfiability

I read many algorithm for finding the 2-SAT problem, i.e. given expression is satisfiable or not, which can be solved in polynomial time. example([algorithm](http://www.iitg.ernet.in/deepkesh/CS301/assignment-2/2sat.pdf)).
For **Krom's procedure**([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability)),I construct graph from which I can easily verify its satisfiability in polynomial time.
Now, I want to find solution of this expression to be satisfiable.
I am thinking like that (verify it): first I take any literal of expression that forms strong connected component say x,and assign value as 0. Then according to algo, there exist edge ( x! -> y). therefore y cannot be 0. (since 1 -> 0 is false) and similarly proceeding if possible.
Otherwise take x=0 and then have only choice as y=1 and similarly proceed to get any 1 instance for which it is satisfiable.

Now, Is any feasible solution of finding **any one** of this in **polynomial time**

- give all possible solutions for which expression is satisfiable.
- Or is this expression is satisfiable for input having total k literals = 1.
- Or how many minimum number of literals have value 1 for expression to be satisfiable.

I am not getting any polynomial algorithm for this types of questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> give all possible solutions for which expression is satisfiable

No, because there can be exponentially many.

> Or is this expression is satisfiable for input having total k literals = 1

No, because if this were easy, then so too would be weighted 2-satisfiability (NP-hard).

> Or how many minimum number of literals have value 1 for expression to be satisfiable

This *is* weighted 2-SAT.

Comment: Thanks @David. By seeing the graph, other than comment about satisfiability, what other information can be drawn.

Comment: @piyush-balwani That's too broad of a question to answer usefully.